# Is there any way to get a true white color?

Tags: themes

Is there any way to get a true white color in ubuntu?

I tried changing the theme to Adwaita Cupertino. Still, my home`s background, including the background of right-click menu is having a small yellowish color. Is there any way to tweak this behaviour ?

I also tried Macbuntu. Still the problem persists. Are these themes supposed to be like that in ubuntu ? No pure white?

Comment: Could it be the screen that's slightly yellowish?

Comment: are you sure it is not just your monitor? I have used a colour finder application to verify that my file browser background is in fact white (#ffffff, or rgb(255,255,255))

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is your monitor settings, or your monitor itself.

I do notice a slight yellow discolouration when switching between ubuntu and windows, however every program I run tells me the white is in fact white.

Try changing your display colour settings and hopefully you have a monitor that allows you to make 'profiles' so you can easily switch back and fourth.

<sub>Look Ma! the white is white!</sub>
[image: looks white to me boss]